# Can I use recursive constraints to define a generic class

Tags: c#, generics

In one of my pet projects I have found myself using generics quite a lot and I'm wondering if it is possible to use recursive constraints in a generic class.

Let's imagine I have the following interface

```
public interface IAmSpecial {}
```

and the classes implementing it can each be handled by its own class

```
public class SpecialHandler<T> where T: IAmSpecial {}
```

I would like to define a class that is generic over any SpecialHandler

```
public class SpecialWrapperHandler<T> where T : SpecialHandler<SpecialT> where SpecialT: IAmSpecial
{
    public SpecialWrapperHandler(T t){}
}
```

which doesn't compile. I can define the `SpecialWrapperHandler` class with the following signature

```
public class SpecialWrapperHandler<T> where T : SpecialHandler<IAmSpecial>
{
    public SpecialWrapperHandler(T t){}
}
```

but then I cannot build it since any `SpecialHandler` implementation will close the generic value on one implementation of `IAmSpecial`. Also I cannot declare something like

```
public class SpecialWrapperHandler<SpecialHandler<T>> where T : IAmSpecial
```

So is it possible to have a C# construct that recurse generic constraints so I can my `SpecialWrapperHandler`? If so what construct should I use? And if not, why? A quick read of the [generics chapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) in the doc doesn't yield many answers...

Comment: try taking in 2 generic arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass in a second type parameter for the handler. In that way you can type both parameters.

Like so:

```
public class SpecialWrapperHandler<H, T> where H : SpecialHandler<T> where T : IAmSpecial
{
    public SpecialWrapperHandler(T t){}
}
```

Proof:

```
public class X : IAmSpecial { }

public class XHandler : SpecialHandler<X> { }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    X x = new X();
    SpecialWrapperHandler<XHandler, X> v = new SpecialWrapperHandler<XHandler, X>(x);
}
```

Comment: That's really obvious in retrospect :( . The upper level of generics must already know the type on which the lower level of generics will close. Thanks